# Collision detection delegate scheme

Tags: delegates, collision-detection, delegation

Hey guys!  My physics engine is coming along quite nicely (thanks for asking!) and I'm ready to start working on some even more advanced junk.  Case in point, I'm trying to set up my collision engine so that an arbitrary delegate can be notified when a collision occurs.  Let me set up a scenario for you:

Say we have object A, object B, and object C in the physics simulation.  I want to be able to inform a delegate about a collision between A and B, AND inform a potentially DIFFERENT delegate about a collision between A and C.

A little background information: I have a known interface for the delegate, I have the potential of storing state for my collision detector (but don't atm), and have the ability to store state in the objects themselves.  Similarly, I use this delegate model to handle collision resolution, simply setting the physics engine as the delegate for all objects by default, allowing the user to change the delegate if desired.

Now, I already tried having each object store it's own collision delegate that would be informed when a collision occurred.  This didn't work because when the objects had the same collision delegate, the same collision was handled twice.  When I switched to only using the delegate of the first object (however that was decided), the order of simulation became an issue.  I want to use a dictionary, but that introduces a significant amount of overhead.  However, that seems like the direction I need to be heading.

So here's the question: fight to the death over a suitable solution.  How would YOU solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must say that it's a bit odd that two objects can have different delegates (at a collision) and still it would be bad if two identical delegates fired at a collision. I seems like they should both fire all the time or only one of them should. Consistency is what bothers me here.
Explaining that would help some more.

Second, if you use the naive version of holding a delegate for each object and then conditioning activating its functionality ("if (!some boolean indicating this delegate was fired already) {do something}"), this could be solved with a very small overhead.
It works, but I don't like this kind of code.

My suggestion (a bit complex, so think about it before working on it) is to try to focus on a manager object which would go over all the delegates and invoke the two that where relevant to the collision.
**For instance**, A and B collide, and the manager is invoked with them as parameters. You now can cycle through all the delegates known to the system (assuming they are few) and fire the ones that match "delegate == a.del or delegate == b.del".
This comes at a greater overhead, but if we are talking about a small number of delegates, if will make very little difference. On the other side this will allow you to expend your collision detection engine in this area further more in the future (like the existence of more then one delegate per object).

Comment: Your suggestion is well founded.  I am currently devising something similar: a controller object takes pairs of physics objects as keys to attain a delegate value.  That delegate is then called with the resulting collision between the two objects.  So when A and B collide, the controller looks for the delegate associated with A&B, and then when A and C collide, it looks for the delegate associated with A&C.  You are right though: this comes at a significant cost as far as storage and complexity.  Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: I've decided to set delegates per TYPE of object, which seems to be an acceptable solution.  Thanks!